# Explain why $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t}dt = 1$.

Tags: improper-integrals, exponential-function

I would appreciate it if someone could show the reasoning for this very elementary result:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t}dt = 1$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\int e^{-t} dt = \int d(-e^{-t}) = -e^{-t} + c$$
Hence,
$$\int_a^b e^{-t} dt = -e^{-b} + e^{-a}$$
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} dt = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b e^{-t} dt = \lim_{b \to \infty} \left(-e^{-b} + e^0 \right) = 1 - \lim_{b \to \infty} e^{-b} = 1 - 0 = 1$$

Comment: Rats! When I began writing my question only the first line in your post appeared...Oh, well, +1.

Comment: I don't think anyone can give a better answer to a beginner then that. Just a straightforward calculation with the precise definition of limits. Couldn't be easier.

Comment: Thanks! I was forgetting about the $e^0$.  :-)